# Google Sheets countif: excluding multiple values and counting everything else

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I have an attendance sheet with over 250 employees and at the end of the day, I want to be able to count who came to work and who was on leave. 
of course, each and every one of the employees has their own rest days and shifts, 
now with that being said, I tried researching and looking around for the best way to count them, 
the reason I am steering away from query is that the file is heavy and massive to start with so it has to be countif or countifs cause I need the number of the end of the day.

I tried using:

```
=countif(G3:G11,"<>RD, <>VL")
```

but it is giving the count of all which doesn't seem right, 
[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SJLQjthaQz049tDr5QbrMndkVDV2zaEO1zqtv6WMXgk/edit#gid=0) is the link to my test sheet 
I would appreciate any help I can get in this regards

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(G3:G11, NOT(REGEXMATCH(G3:G11, "RD|VL")))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried it but it gave me "0"

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SJLQjthaQz049tDr5QbrMndkVDV2zaEO1zqtv6WMXgk/edit?usp=sharing i edited to make it anyone can edit

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful